# CommandNotFoundException printed when executed via Packer for Amazon powershell scripts

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, packer

While trying to create an AMI using Packer getting the error - CommandNotFoundException

Wrote the below line in packer -

```
build {
  sources = ["source.amazon-ebs.windows-2019"]
    provisioner "powershell" {
    inline = [
        "C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\EC2-Windows\\Launch\\Scripts\\InitializeInstance.ps1 -Schedule",
        "C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\EC2-Windows\\Launch\\Scripts\\SysprepInstance.ps1 -NoShutdown"
        ]
  }
}
```

Packer console logs -

```
==> amazon-ebs.windows-2019: Provisioning with Powershell...
==> amazon-ebs.windows-2019: Provisioning with powershell script: C:\Users\UIF30855\AppData\Local\Temp\powershell-provisioner1857881635
==> amazon-ebs.windows-2019: C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeInstance.ps1 : The term
==> amazon-ebs.windows-2019: 'C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeInstance.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
==> amazon-ebs.windows-2019: function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
==> amazon-ebs.windows-2019: path is correct and try again.
==> amazon-ebs.windows-2019: At C:\Windows\Temp\script-64993cb4-61c2-d83d-5dcf-d8a452c02387.ps1:1 char:1
==> amazon-ebs.windows-2019: + C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeInstance.p ...
==> amazon-ebs.windows-2019: + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
==> amazon-ebs.windows-2019:     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\ProgramData\...izeInstance.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
==> amazon-ebs.windows-2019:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
==> amazon-ebs.windows-2019:
```

Comment: Show us the packer config

Comment: build {
  sources = ["source.amazon-ebs.windows-2019"]
    provisioner "powershell" {
    inline = [
        "C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\EC2-Windows\\Launch\\Scripts\\InitializeInstance.ps1 -Schedule",
        "C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\EC2-Windows\\Launch\\Scripts\\SysprepInstance.ps1 -NoShutdown"
        ]
  }
}

Comment: Add that to the question

Comment: Try starting an instance from the base AMI. Are those scripts there?

Comment: @Paolo - Do you need the complete hcl file?

Answer (score 0):

Without checking the full hcl file I can't be sure that these files are missing in the base image.
However, I recommend tow ways to check the cause of the problem:

- modify inline commands to list content of C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts

```
provisioner "powershell" {
  inline = [
    "cd C:/ProgramData/Amazon/EC2-Windows/Launch/Scripts",
    "ls"
  ]
}
provisioner "powershell" {
  inline = [
    "cd C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\EC2-Windows\\Launch\\Scripts",
    "ls"
  ]
}
```

- or just change double backslashes to forward slash

```
provisioner "powershell" {
  inline = [
    "C:/ProgramData/Amazon/EC2-Windows/Launch/Scripts/InitializeInstance.ps1 -Schedule",
    "C:/ProgramData/Amazon/EC2-Windows/Launch/Scripts/SysprepInstance.ps1 -NoShutdown"
  ]
}
```

[offcial example from documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/plugins/builders/amazon/ebs#windows-2016-sysprep-commands-for-amazon-windows-amis-only), [another example](https://gist.github.com/manics/7fc064e590406616bba4a76a0f286c27)